# Subview behaves strangely in navigation-based app

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uitableview, subview

I'm currently developing an app for iphone (my first) and I used several `UITableViewController` for navigation.

I then used a subview attached to `self.view.superview` to get a non-scroll image at the top. 
The subview is created in IB, simple `UIView` with an `UIImageView` in it.

I'm adding the subview in `viewDidAppear` and this functions well. 
But as soon as I'm tapping a cell and the navigationController pushes the next View animated, the previous view (scrolling out of sight) becomes completely white and my subview moves animated to the center. It's only for a half second or so, because then it's gone due to the next view arriving, but it's really unnerving.

I tried removing the subview in `viewWillDisappear`, that removes the `UIImageView`, but the screen still becomes completely white.

Does anybody how to fix this?

Oh, and PS: I'm working only on the Simulator, because I have no Developer Account yet. And I cannot change everything to a ViewController because I have a deadline to meet.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be surprised that things go wrong when you mess with the views of view controllers that don't belong to you. Rather than using a table view controller, you should replace it with a custom `UIViewController` whose view acts as a container view for both the table view and the non-scrolling view above it.